# Simultaneous fetch() in Backbone failing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to achieve something that seems like it should be relatively trivial for Backbone, but is not working. I am populating a graph with series as per a user's actions. The code is below.

Let's say the user adds two series quickly. Or a route fires both series simultaneously. The constant is that the second fetch is fired before the first one is returned. In this case, 'fetching' is logged twice, but 'fetched' is only logged once. Is this expected behaviour, and if not how should I structure my code for it to work?

```
# Series model
class Series extends Backbone.Model
    initialize: (options) ->
        _.bindAll @
        @endpoint = state?.getEndpoint()

    url: ->
        [localApiUrl, 'metrics', @endpoint, @.get('id')].join('/')



class SeriesCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Series,

    initialize: ->
        _.bindAll @
        @bind 'add', @fetched

    fetchData: ( opts ) =>
        console.log('fetching')
        @series = new Series({ id: opts.id })
        @series.fetch
            success: (model, response) =>
                @.add({
                    id: @series.get('id')
                    name: @series.get('id')
                    data : @series.get('ts')
                    marker:
                        radius: 2
                    turboThreshold: 10000 
                    dataGrouping: 
                        enabled: false
                })

    fetched: () ->
        console.log('fetched', @)
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but you might get a better response posting the actual javascript.. I should probably learn coffee-script, it can't be that hard, but atm I can't read that without straining.. 8)

Comment: Sorry, used to be the same. I would highly encourage taking the jump, especially if you are doing Backbone stuff. So much nicer and easier to read. For me it took an afternoon to learn (and I'm by no means a l33t js guy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a duplicate model to a collection doesn't do anything; in particular, it won't trigger an `"add"` event because nothing will be added. Consider this:

```
# c is an empty collection
c.add(id: 1, t: 'where is')
c.add(id: 2, t: 'pancakes house?')
c.add(id: 1, t: 'different')
```

That will generate two `"add"` events and the collection will end up with `(1, 'where is')` and `(2, 'pancakes house?')` as models, the third `add` will be ignored.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/WUH6f/

The [0.9.2 changelog](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#changelog) has this to say:

> - Instead of throwing an error when adding duplicate models to a collection, Backbone will now silently skip them instead.

So if `fetchData` gets called twice, you'll get two calls to `console.log('fetching')`. But, if `opts.id` is the same for both calls to `fetchData`, then the second `@add` will be ignored because there's already a model with `id == opts.id` in the collection.

---

You say that `opts.id` is different each time but that doesn't necessarily mean that `@series.get('id')` will be different. Remember that the *A* in *AJAX* stands for *asynchronous* so you're probably seeing a sequence of events similar to this:

1. Something calls `fetchData(id: 1)`. `@series.id` will now be 1.
2. The AJAX call is made.
3. Something calls `fetchData(id: 2)`. `@series.id` will now be 2. Remember that `@series` is an *instance variable*, not a local variable.
4. The server returns from the first AJAX call and the `success` handler is triggered. `@series.id` is now 2 and the `Series` from **3** will be added.
5. The server returns from the second AJAX call and the success handler is triggered. `@series.id` is still 2 so the `Series` from **3** will be added again. But this one will be a duplicate so `add` will ignore you.

You should be able to get around this by using a plain old local variable for the series in question rather than an instance variable:

```
fetchData: ( opts ) =>
    console.log('fetching')
    series = new Series({ id: opts.id })
    series.fetch
        success: (model, response) =>
            @add(
                id: series.get('id')
                #...
            )
```

You didn't need the `.` in `@.add` so I took it out. I also dropped the braces in the `@add` call as you don't need them either; you could drop the parentheses as well but I left them in as I find they help clarify the code's block structure.

I should have spotted this problem in the first place, sorry.

Comment: +1 because this answers a problem I had solved myself but not understood the reason for

Comment: Unfortunately opts is different each time, so this answer is incorrect. Or correct, but not the solution to the problem I'm having.

Comment: @FredStevens-Smith: `opts` may be different but `@series` might not be. I've added an update that probably explains what's going on.

Comment: @muistooshort: thanks. Marked accepted. Solution involved rewriting my crappy code, but this was very helpful.